What makes a question a check my work question and not conceptual?
A question I asked has been closed as a check my work question. This is in no regards a check my work question. It is asking about a concept regarding friction and whether or not it changes when the mass of body it is acting upon changes with time. Why has this been marked as check my work?

Welcome Pratham Pawan to Physics Stack Exchange. When asking on Meta about a specific question, please include a link to that question.

How is “ Should if would like to ask whether their is an error in my conceptual understanding…. any helps in rectifying the error in my logic will be highly appreciated!  ” not check-my-work or homework-type?

@ZeroTheHero I am wary of binning all posts with a phrase like that as "check my work", since any conceptual misunderstanding could have that phrase added to it.

@BioPhysicist yes some judgement is required but IMO this is “check-my-work”.  It doesn’t mean the question is bad, just that it is badly worded, and this is a distinction that is often lost.  The OP can easily edit if indeed the question is conceptual.

@ZeroTheHero I agree, and hopefully my answer below helps capture that

I would also add that just adding the phrase "what am I conceptually missing" to a question is also not good as we don't know what you don't know. OP needs to write something along the lines of "I don't understand why X is the case in this scenario because I thought...." (obviously finishing the sentence).


this is in no regards a check my work question and is asking about a concept regarding friction and how it changes or does not when the mass of body it is acting upon changes with time

You have highlighted the purpose of your question. You want to understand if the acceleration due to friction of a sliding object depends on the object's mass. This is borderline check my work, but I suggest editing your question to really highlight the conceptual issues you are having.
Typically framing a problem as

Here is an exercise (irrelevant if it was assigned as homework or not)
Here is how I think it should be solved
Here is the answer provided to me, it does not match what I did.
What am I missing?

gives a huge impression of "check my work", even if your intent was to hone in on conceptual misunderstandings.
